# scheme define cdr contract violation expected pair given '()

Tags: scheme, racket

Given the define tree:

```
(define tree
  '("S" (("-" ("A" 3333) ("A" 4444))
         ("W" (("+" ("R" 0) ("R" 1))
               ("+" ("R" 1) ("R" 2))
               ("+" ("R" 2) ("R" 3))
               ("+" ("R" 3) ("R" 4))
               ("+" ("R" 4) ("R" 5)))
              (("-" ("R" 0) ("R" 1))
               ("-" ("R" 1) ("R" 2))
               ("-" ("R" 2) ("R" 3))   
               ("-" ("R" 3) ("R" 4))
               ("-" ("A" 1000) ("A" 2000)))))))
```

I am trying to access the values. Doing `car` and `cdr` works for the first and getting the rest but when I try to get a specific value like `("A" 1000)` I get the error:

> cdr: contract violation
>     expected: pair?
>     given: '().

I have tried `(car (cdr (cdr (cdr '(tree)))))`, `(cdddr tree)` but I always get that error. Any helpful tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must not put `tree` inside a list: `'(tree)`, that's just a list with the symbol `'tree`, with no relationship with the value of the actual variable you defined before. And to access the desired element, do this:

```
(car (cdr (car (car (cdr tree)))))
=> '("A" 3333)
```

Also, I'd like to suggest that you rethink the way you're representing and/or traversing the information, as you can see, it's pretty hard to extract data out of such a complex tree...

Comment: ok yea I found a way to access the info better by caadr, but traversing through the tree I'm coming into a wall. I was trying to use recursion if if didn't equal the last node then it would call it self. But I can't figure out a way to actually move my position without hard coding it in